# travis osx brew install --with-toolchain always times out

Tags: macos, travis-ci

Any ideas how to install llvm in a travis build for osx?

I need clang, llvm-ar, llvm-link but not much else.

`before_install:
  - if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "osx" ]]; then brew install -v --with-toolchain llvm ; fi`

Invariably fails, since it takes way longer than 35 minutes to build the entire toolchain.  Even if I try the more conservative build

`- if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "osx" ]]; then brew install -v --with-toolchain --without-compiler-rt --without-libffi --without-libcxx llvm ; fi`

it still times out after 46 minutes at about 56% built.

Since I can't build it, I can't use the travis cache, so I suppose I need to
get a pre built version.

I have made my own bottle, but how to get it into the travis box? It is big (782M). I have server infrastructure at my fingertips, so if setting up a server to serve the bottle is the way to go, just point me to some docs.

Comment: Tried wget-ing the bottle too, but it also times out. I suppose I could try and make a smaller bottle.

Comment: OK so I trimmed down the llvm formula to https://github.com/SRI-CSL/homebrew-sri-csl/blob/master/Formula/llvm_lite.rb  and then made a bottle. I could wget it (in time), so I just have to debug my bottle and formula and hopefully I am done. Hard work for the small gain.

Comment: Solved: https://github.com/ianamason/gllvm

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by installing from a binary release. This also has the nice property that it unifies linux and mac install process. See this [.travis.yml](https://github.com/mmcloughlin/hellollvm/blob/de9244a2cbfe399b354e70b44a2b28c03625890b/.travis.yml) for an example.

Comment: Yes but when a new version of LLVM comes out, there is not a binary version until ...